# How do I plot a list all at once with matplotlib.pyplot?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I created a program that works out primes. It was just a test but I thought it would be interesting to then plot this on a graph.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

max = int(input("What is your max no?: "))
primeList = []

for x in range(2, max + 1):
  isPrime = True
  for y in range (2 , int(x ** 0.5) + 1):
     if x % y == 0:
        isPrime = False
        break

     if isPrime:
        primeList.append(x)


print(primeList)
```

How can I then plot `primeList`, can I do it all at once outside of the for loop?

Comment: Currently you're not plotting anything? Also, what would you plot against on your `x-axis`? You just need to supply x/y pairs in lists of equal length.

Comment: `plt.plot(range(len(primeList)), primeList)` for example.

Comment: I had an extra block of code that plotted that and a variable called itemsInList which was the amount of items in primeList

Comment: thanks @roganjosh that worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This plots your list vs. its index:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.plot(primeList, 'o')
plt.show()
```

This program:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

max_= 100
primeList = []

for x in range(2, max_ + 1):
    isPrime = True
    for y in range (2, int(x ** 0.5) + 1):
        if x % y == 0:
            isPrime = False
            break
    if isPrime:
        primeList.append(x)

plt.plot(primeList, 'o')
plt.show()
```

yields this plot:

[image]